# Add Spring Boot module to grails project

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a Grails Project (grails version 3.3.9) which has multiple grails modules.
Now I want to add a new Spring Boot module to the project.
I am able to add the Spring Boot module but don't know how to include this in the build. 
I have tried to create a JAR file and add it to the project as a dependency in the build.gradle file.
The controllers in the Jar are Rest Controllers and I am trying to invoke the Rest Endpoints. However I get 404 error. I have tried to access the controllers directly but get the same response.

Steps to add the jar:
In the build.gradle file under repositories section added the below line

```
flatDir{
    dirs '../demo1/build/libs'
}
```

And in the dependencies section added

```
compile 'com.xms.platform:demo1:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: "I have tried to create a JAR file and add it to the project as a dependency in the build.gradle file." - That works.  Can you show the technique you attempted?

Comment: If you are you expecting your Spring Boot controllers to be recognized as Grails controllers, I don't think that will work.

Comment: The controller I am trying to access in the Jar is a Rest Controller. So I am trying to invoke the Rest endpoint. Apologies I should have mentioned it in the initial question.